# If $0\leq f(x)\leq c \int_0^x f(t) dt$, then does that imply that $f'(x)\leq cf(x)$ on $(0,b)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $0\leq f(x)\leq c \int_0^x f(t) dt$, then does that imply that $f'(x)\leq cf(x)$ on $(0,b)$? Assuming f is continuous and differentiable.

(note c>0)
I cant think of a counter example..anybody know more about this?

maybe since integral f(t)dt has series expansion (at x=0) = f(0)t + f'(0)t^2/2+ ...
that has something to do with it?

Comment: You might find [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) helpful, in particular the integral form.

Comment: Hey T.Bongers, I looked at it but am not sure which part I should be focusing on. Namely, do you know if my identity is correct? Then I can concentrate on proving it. Thanks

Comment: Look in particular at [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions), taking $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta = c$.

Comment: but wouldn't taking alpha=0 make the whole integral 0 since there's alpha(s) there?

Comment: Yes: The original inequality implies that $f$ is identically zero, so the inequality $f' \le c f$ holds pretty easily.

Comment: ah ok that's because 0<=0?

Comment: Right: Both $f$ and $f'$ are identically zero, and $0 \le 0$.

Comment: Also in general, if f(0)= g(0), and f<= cg, then does f'<=cg'?

Comment: No: $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = x$ give a counterexample.

Comment: nevermind, got it thanks a bunch!

Comment: Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ so that we have $0 \leq F'(x) \leq cF(x)$. Now use this answer (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/671975/72031) to show that $F(x) = 0$ and $F'(x) = f(x) = 0, f'(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take. This is essentially the Bellman-Gronwall inequality except it is computed iteratively.

Define the operator $L:C[0,b] \to C[0,b]$ by  $(Lf)(x) = c\int_0^x f(t) dt$. Note that $L$ preserves order in the sense that if $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$, then
$(Lf)(x) \le (Lg)(x)$ for all $x$.

We are given $f(x) \le (Lf)(x)$ for all $x$. Applying $L$ to both sides and using the original inequality again gives $f(x) \le (L^2f)(x)$ for all $x$. Repeating
gives $f(x) \le (L^n f)(x)$ for all $x$ and $n$.

Expanding gives $(L^n f)(x) = c^n\int_{t_n=0}^x \cdots \int_{t_1=0}^{t_2} f(t_1) dt_1 \cdots dt_n$. Let $K = \sup_x |f(x)|$, then we have
$(L^n f)(x) \le c^n K \int_{t_n=0}^x \cdots \int_{t_1=0}^{t_2} dt_1 \cdots dt_n$, which evaluates to $(L^n f)(x) \le K { (cx)^n \over n!} \le K { (cb)^n \over n!}$.

Taking limits shows that $f(x) \le 0$ for all $x$, from which we get $f = 0$.