# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}}$ exists, then it must equal 0

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that, in a deleted neighborhood of 0, f is differentiable with $f'\neq 0$ and that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. Prove that if $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}}$ exists, then it must equal 0.

This question is included in L'Hospital Rule's section, but I don't know how to apply the rule here.

It seems to me that if f is differentiable with $f'\neq 0$, then $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}}$ is not a form of $\frac{0}{0}$. Then I don't know what to show now. Any hints?

Comment: Why would this help to solve the problem here?

Comment: This is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1619990/148510). Essentially a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Easy exercise: If $g$ has bounded derivative on $(a,b),$ then $g$ is bounded on $(a,b).$ Hint: fix a point $x_0\in (a,b),$ write $g(x)=g(x)-g(x_0) +g(x_0),$ and apply the MVT to $g(x)-g(x_0).$

Now in our problem suppose $f(x)/f'(x) \to L \ne 0.$ Then $f'(x)/f(x) \to 1/L.$ But note $f'(x)/f(x)=(\ln |f|)'(x).$ Thus $(\ln |f|)'$ is bounded in a deleted neighborhood $0.$ From the exercise, $\ln |f|$ is bounded near $0.$ But that contradicts $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0.$ Therefore $f(x)/f'(x) \to 0.$

Comment: I changed my hint to a more complete solution-mainly because this question is being cited above as a duplicate, and I think my solution is different from the ones on offer at those links (and possibly easier).